# SQL: Show transactions since last zero balance

Tags: sql

I'm trying to display all of a customer's transactions since they last had a zero balance.

The current report I have displays transactions according to dates I input manually, using the following SQL:

```
SELECT    rmledg.chgcode, 
          trandate, 
          nameid, 
          srccode, 
          rmledg.descrptn, 
          tranamt, 
          chkdesc, 
          posted, 
          rmbatchid, 
          namegroup, 
          NULL, 
          chgcode.class 
FROM      rmledg 
LEFT JOIN chgcode 
ON        chgcode.chgcode=rmledg.chgcode 
WHERE     trandate>=qrydate{[BEGIN]} 
AND       trandate <=qrydate{[END]} 
AND       rmledg.namegroup='CELL{NAMEGROUP}'
```

The stuff in {brackets} are variables within the program.

I see a lot of tips around the net as to how to calculate the current balance, but not how to return all of the transactions since last zero balance.

This is for a Late Letter.  We want to show everything that's happened since the person was last paid in full.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  etc.

Comment: As asked above, what DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) are you using, and also what **version** are you using (SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014, etc.)?

Comment: I believe it is SQL Server 2008, but this is all happening within a program called MRI (real estate management software), which may have its own limitations.

Comment: CORRECTION: Part of the program install appears to be a SQL Server 2005 component.

Comment: Could somebody at least point me in the right direction?  As best I can tell I need to do two things:  1) Dynamically create a running "balance" column, and 2) somehow only pull up transactions after that balance was last at zero.